# Having videos in Jade

Tags: html, html5-video, pug

I am making a website using Node.js and Jade in Expressjs and I want to embed a video. I also want to have a video player that has the capabilities to fast forward and rewind. I was wondering if Jade has the capabilities to do this because I have searched everywhere and cannot find one example of playing videos in Jade.

I know HTML5 has the video tag, but I'm having problems trying to convert it and it won't play my video. Here is my Jade code:

```
video(width='320', height='240', controls='controls', autoplay='autoplay')
 source(src='/movieTest.ogg', type='video/ogg')
  object(data='/movieTest.ogg', width='320', height='240')
   embed(width='320', height='240', src='/movieTest.ogg')
```

Can I do this in Jade or do I need to find another way? (super helpful if you tell me how)

Comment: Jade only converts to html, so you can do anything that you can do with html. Does the html-output look right? Is the movie available from domain/movieTest.ogg?

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure object should not be inside the source element.

Comment: If you are struggling getting it working in Jade, bust out into plain old html by starting the line with a pipe `|`

Comment: Got same issue seems like source element should be ended by </source> but jade doesn't produce such output. I had to use `|` to make it work.

Comment: It turns out that there is some issue with `type` param inside `source` tag which makes it work in plain HTML but no through jade

Answer (score 3):

You have several things to fix. Your code is not well indented and is not correct because it has mistakes (notice **autoplay** attribute). Below you can see a correct piece of code:

```
video(width='320', height='240', autoplay='')
    source(src='/video/movie.mp4', type='video/mp4')
    source(src='/video/movie.ogg', type='video/ogg')
```

Videos should be stored in the **public** folder in Express scafolding.

You can see a demo at http://audiolibros.azurewebsites.net/.

And you can see the source code at [GitHub](https://github.com/pmargom/NodeMySQLSamples/blob/master/views/index.jade).

Finally, a great tool to convert html2jade.org can help you

Hope this helps,

Regards.